# Use Ansible to remove images based on the label using docker_prune

Tags: docker, ansible, devops, docker-image, docker-cleanup

I would like to remove all docker images, which are not labeled with 2 or more labels. Since Ansible 2.8 there is a [docker_prune command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_prune_module.html), which I would like to use in combination with the images_filter options like this:

```
docker_prune:
  debug: yes
  containers: no
  images: yes
  images_filters:
    label: not label1 label2
    dangling: false
```

In the [docker prune documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/#filtering) there is an easy way to to that:

```
docker image prune --filter="label!=label1!=label2"
```

Is there any way to negate the label option in the command or is the only way to loop over the docker_prune with the help of a label list?

Comment: then you may use sh not the plugin I think

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I wrote that from memory. The command works like this:

```
$ docker system prune --help

Usage:  docker system prune [OPTIONS]

Remove unused data

Options:
  -a, --all             Remove all unused images not just dangling ones
      --filter filter   Provide filter values (e.g. 'label=<key>=<value>')
  -f, --force           Do not prompt for confirmation
      --volumes         Prune volumes
```

So, it should have similar options instead:

```
- name: prune docker
  docker_prune:
    volumes: true
    tagged_images: true
    filters:
    - label!=<key>
```

The currently supported filters for label:

```
label (label=<key>, label=<key>=<value>, label!=<key>, or label!=<key>=<value>) - only remove containers, images, networks, and volumes with or ( without, in case label!=... is used) the specified labels.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this syntax doesn't work for me.